# Categorizing date by week with dynamic alias name

Tags: sql, oracle

We have one column in our table which stores a number of records in "date" type, we want to separate them by each week and find the number of repetitions for each week that we have in our column.
the database is in oracle.
I think for creating a dynamic alias name we need cursor.
this image below may help:

[image]

Comment: which database are you  using?

Comment: oracle database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use mysql function week()

here the info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

an example

```
select concat('Week ',week(date)), count(date)
from table
group by week(date)
```

Comment: thanks for answering but 1- the code gives week + number in two different column, 2- it doesn't count the number of date which happened in a week

Comment: Ok the second column returns the count of dates that occurs in the week (first column), try with this changes  select concat('week ',week(date)), count(date)
from table
group by week(date)

Comment: it works properly in MySQL and we need to_char(to_date(date,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW')
in oracle
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax;

```
SELECT     to_char(date,'WW') week, COUNT(date) number
FROM       your_table
GROUP  BY  to_char(date,'WW')
```

Have a look at [TO_CHAR](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) function.